# Problem with connecting belkin router to adsl modem/router

Tags: modem

Maybe someone can help me a little further with a problem.

The problem is that I have two modems, there are two dsl lines, everything is working perfectly, accept when I plug a Belkin router on one of these modems, the router doesn't give me internet.

I have the following modem/routers

Experiabox Speedtouch 780 WL, on this modem, the Belkin works great!

and a

Thomson TG787, when I plug the router on this modem, I don't have internet.

I can't tell you the specifications of both modems at this moment, but maybe someone knows in a instant why internet isn't working on the  TG787 with a extra Belkin router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable DHCP server in the EXTRA router IE the thomson router. then it will be as a pass through or SWITCH and you should not have any more problem. Remember that after you turn off DHCP you will not be able to reach that routers home page untill you do a hard reset on the router. also remeber to plug the connection into one of the ports 1-4 and not the WAN or Internet port. once done you shouldn't have any more problems(the most probably problem is that both routers are giving ip address but on Two different gateways IE  192.168.0.1 and 192.168.1.1  if this is true the you will NOT get internet because the two gateways are not communicating.) so by getting rid of one DHCP the other gets to create the connections.

Good LUCK!!!

Comment: ok, I understand that, but the problem is that the second router is on a whole other location connected by a cable. Because they are both routers, is there a way I can use them both with routing capabilities?

When I place them both in different ranges, and give the second router as gateway the ip adres of the first modem/router?

Comment: so its three routers. two which are your internet connections and the other is a spare router. Now HOW do you want your setup. Because either way, if you connect to the thomson with the belkin and disable the dhcp on the belking it will use the router of the internet AND bridge EVERY connection to it including wireless. you can also plug in the other router to it as well and the same operation will happen. now if you want to keep BOTH DHCP(which will make your network UNSTABLE AND NOT get correct ip address at times) It all has to do with your router's compatibility with OTHER routers.

Comment: No, there are two routers, but I want to keep them both with routing capabilities, but that could make it as you say Unstable.

When I disable the DHCP on the Belkin, does it mean I get the IP adres from the Thomson's DHCP service, and use the Belkin as extension/bridge? and. is this the Access point function?

If this is true, can more then 1 computer be connected to the Belkin?

Comment: absolutly!! now the belking will just be an extention of your thomson's dhcp service. and you can connect as many connections as you want to the belking wired and wireless. you can also extend your network even MORE through the same process.

Comment: yes the belking can act as an acess point. so be sure to make all your settings BEFORE you disable the dhcp because as i said you will lose the routers admin page once you do that.(turning off dhcp turns off the ip address of the router so there is no more 192.168.1.1  its just a passthough now.)

Comment: if this works hit me up with a check and a point...its hard work helping people and all i get paid is POINTS Thanks Man!!

Comment: Here you are, I'll try it wednessday, You will have the points in advance, but if it not works, you will ask a very dumb question and I'll answer it akay ;-)

Comment: haha...i will still help you...and yes NO PROBLEM...i need more people like you...lol...i am Sure this will work. it has to be the gateways blocking the internet...but turning off dhcp will make your belking just a Bridge for the rest of the network.. remember to put it into one of the ports ...1-4 and not into the WAN connection.(might say WAN or INTERNET)

Comment: i was thinking that wendnesday is sooo long...
but im still here if you decide to do it early...

Comment: how is it going??